# Can azure jupyterlab vscode open Rmd files?

Tags: vscode-extensions, jupyter-lab, azure-machine-learning-service

Microsoft's Azure [claims to offer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) integration with jupyterlab, which I would be quite keen to use (editing code in a browser really starts to irritate one after a while). However, I am using [Rmd files](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/issues/8) in jupyterlab so as to maintain the notebooks in git.

When I tried to connect to jupyterlab from azure by clicking the "open in vscode" button I just got an editor for the Rmd file itself which didn't seem very helpful.

Is there a way of using Rmd files in jupyterlab with vscode?  (preferrably without a whole bunch of exporting and importing using e.g. `jupytext`)

Comment: The website you linked does not mention JupyterLab at all.

Comment: It's kind of moot whether it's jupyterlab or jupyter if vscode is acting as the interface to the kernel.... azure let's you connect to a jupyterlab instance on it's computers.